# jq won't allow to iterate over results

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

In code below I'm trying to match values from a bash array with values from json array using jq.

```
PROJECTS=$(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_URL}/api/v4/projects")
for GITLAB_TAG in "${GITLAB_TAGS[@]}"; do
    PROJECTS=`echo "${PROJECTS}" \
    | jq --arg gitlab_tag "$GITLAB_TAG" '[ .[] | select(.tag_list[] | contains($gitlab_tag)) ]'`
done

PROJECTS=$(echo "$PROJECTS" | jq -r '.[]')
```

Consider the following JSON payload as a sample API response:

```
[{"id":31,"description":"","default_branch":null,"tag_list":["dev","app"],"archived":false,"visibility":"private"},{"id":28,"description":"","default_branch":"master","tag_list":["dev","app"],"archived":false,"visibility":"private"}]
```

This works only partially, because I can't iterate over results ($PROJECTS).

`printf "${PROJECTS[0]}"` prints the whole array.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON payload? That way you'll get more help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can put all the tags together: `echo "..json..." | jq --argjson gitlab_tag '["dev", "app"]' '.[] | select(.tag_list | contains($gitlab_tag))'`. And pass it as a JSON argument.

Comment: I took that approach and the result is the same. My json entries are properly filtered but I can't iterate over the results.
`printf "${PROJECTS[0]}"` prints out everything instead of first json object.

Comment: That's because `PROJECTS` is not a shell array; it's a regular variable that contains a string whose value is a JSON-encoded array.

Comment: @chepner That's what I thought too. But this won't work too:
`declare -a PROJECTS=$(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_URL}/api/v4/projects" | jq --argjson gitlab_tags '["dev", "app"]' -cr '.[] | select(.tag_list | contains($gitlab_tags))')`

Comment: @chepner If I do `declare -a PROJECTS=($(curl ... ))`. Then it would probably work if one of the value didn't contain "\n" character.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you should be using `index/1` to check .tag_list (not .tag_list[]):

```
[ .[] | select(.tag_list | index($gitlab_tag))
```

jq has no knowledge of bash array variables.  For these, you therefore have two basic options: 1) use bash to iterate over the bash array variable (calling jq as often as necessary); 2) present the contents of the bash array variable in a way that jq can handle.

There are many variations of (2).  Consider for example:

```
$ a=(a "b c")

$ printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | jq -R | jq -s  
[
  "a",
  "b c"
]
```

Comment: Both, solutions: mine and yours work fine. The problem is, that I can't iterate over $PROJECTS. It's treated as string for some reason...

Comment: @MessiOfPHP - See updated answer.  Don't forget that ${PROJECTS[@]} is not the same as "${PROJECTS[@]}".